# Confusion about notation for a metric space.

Tags: metric-spaces

My professor wants me to prove that  $(\mathbb{R},|\cdot|)$ is a complete metric. Now, I know how to do so, but I am confused as to what she is referring to by $$|\cdot|$$ Is she referring to the norm in $\mathbb{R}$? I don't particularly know what the metric is itself.

Comment: yes, it's given by the absolute value function $d(x,y)=|x-y|$. Though what your professor intends exactly is unclear. Did you see a construction of the reals?

Comment: I'm not particularly sure. That is all she wrote for the problem. I am working on metric spaces and completions. The next problem is supposed to work off this and is to prove that the euclidean metric is complete; which I understand.

Comment: @IttayWeiss So are we going to go ahead and assume for sure that this is the usual metric?

Comment: Are we sure the professor does not mean multiplication?